# java implementing moving average

Tags: java, statistics

I am writing a stats object.  I want to track the average with minimal information

I currently have a method:

```
public synchronized void setSuccessful(long time) {
    int succCount = _successful.get(); // atomic int
    _successful.incrementAndGet();
    long maxTime = _maxSuccessfulTimeNano.get(); // atomic long
    if (time > maxTime) {
        _maxSuccessfulTimeNano.set(time);
    }
    long avg = ((_avgSuggessfulTimeNano.get() /* atomic long */ * succCount) + time) / (succCount + 1);
    _avgSuggessfulTimeNano.set(avg);
}
```

Is there a better way of implementing this? or is there a better stats to acquire

Comment: The question better be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: (terminology) that's just an average, not a *moving* average. You might be interested in [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) which is a nice online algorithm that allows to compute the variance in addition.

Comment: The usecase was the backing data for an mbean.  As a task was performed I want to track the time it took to performed, so rather than maintain a collection of times for each individual tasks and calculate the average on demand, I wanted to recalculate the averages for this new task.  And on demand just return the current value.